# creating sqlite db using datamodel c# windows Store App

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-store-apps, sqlite-net

I'm trying to create a sqlite db locally in a Windows Store app using C#.

I keep getting the error

> don't know about sqliteDataGroup...

when using the data model below to create the tables.  I'm using sqlite-net and extensions.

Any ideas what I'm, doing wrong?

```
public class sqliteDataItem
{
    public sqliteDataItem()
    {

    }

    public sqliteDataItem(int Id, String title, String subtitle, String Image, String description, String itemcontent, int groupid)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Subtitle = subtitle;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Image = Image;
        this.ItemContent = itemcontent;
        this.GroupId = groupid;
    }

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(sqliteDataGroup))]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string ItemContent { get; set; }
    [ManyToOne]
    public sqliteDataGroup sqliteDataGroup { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Title;
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Generic group data model.
/// </summary>
public class sqliteDataGroup
{
    public sqliteDataGroup()
    {

    }

    public sqliteDataGroup(int Id, String title, String subtitle, String Image, String description)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Subtitle = subtitle;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Image = Image;
        this.Items = new List<sqliteDataItem>();
    }

    [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    [OneToMany]
    public List<sqliteDataItem> Items { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your conventions connected with names of classes is terrible. Would you give piece of code, where you create the table in db ?

Comment: Code is not complete :
     var db = new SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection(_qDataSource._LocalDBPath);

              
                await db.CreateTableAsync<sqliteDataGroup>();
                await db.CreateTableAsync<sqliteDataItem>();

Comment: Yeah and I should learn the conventions and follow them, I get this a lot, but that doesn't invalidate my question nor does it mean the code won't work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest add the facade which will be helpfull if you want to use sqlite net

```
public static class SqLiteFacade
{
    private static SQLiteConnection _sqlLiteConnection;
    private static string _nameOfDatabase = "databaseName.db";

    public static async Task<bool> InitializeDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            _sqlLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), await GetPathOfDatabaseInstance(_nameOfDatabase));

            _sqlLiteConnection.CreateTable<SqliteDataItem>();
            _sqlLiteConnection.CreateTable<SqliteDataGroup>();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static SQLiteConnection DbConnection
    {
        get
        {
            return _sqlLiteConnection;;
        }
    }

    public static async Task<string> GetPathOfDatabaseInstance(string databaseName)
    {
        if (!await DatabaseExist(databaseName))
        {
            var sampleFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(databaseName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        }

        var database = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(databaseName);
        return database.Path;
    }

    private static async Task<bool> DatabaseExist(string databaseName)
    {
        var files = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFilesAsync();

        return files.Any(file => file.Name == databaseName);
    }
}
```

Your models:

```
public class SqliteDataGroup
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<SqliteDataItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class SqliteDataItem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemContent { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(typeof(SqliteDataGroup))]
    public int SqliteDataGroupId { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use and valid your solution:

```
    if (await SqLiteFacade.InitializeDatabase())
    {
        var group = new SqliteDataGroup()
        {
            Description = "desc",
            Title = "my title",
            Image = "img",
            Subtitle = "subtitle",
            Items = new List<SqliteDataItem>()
                {
                    new SqliteDataItem()
                    {
                        ItemContent = "Item 1"
                    },
                    new SqliteDataItem()
                    {
                        ItemContent = "Item 2"
                    },
                    new SqliteDataItem()
                    {
                        ItemContent = "Item 3"
                    }
                }
        };

        SqLiteFacade.DbConnection.InsertWithChildren(group);
        var results = SqLiteFacade.DbConnection.GetAllWithChildren<SqliteDataGroup>();
    }
```

Check if in the *results* are the results of operation. In my case I use only [this nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions/). The first of all uninstall other extensions. Then you can try using async operations based on [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions.Async/)

Comment: I tried your solution, and it gives the exact same error : don't know about SqliteDataItem.  In the database, I can see SqliteDataItem table.  It gives the error on the next statement : _sqlLiteConnection.CreateTable<SqliteDataGroup>();

Comment: Where you use InitializeDatabase ? In App.xaml.cs ?

Comment: Do you use Universal App template ? Do you create your model in Shared project or in the external PCL project ?

Comment: using windows store app template.  Calling the function from a subpage to App.Xaml.cs Model is not shared at all at this time. But I don't see how the error is related to "where it is called" ;-).

Comment: I found a solution : not use use linked tables :p
I'm creating the database tables, without a link in the datamodel and do that myself in the query's where I pull the data.  I'd still like to see it working WITH the datamodel above; but since I'm pressed for time ;-)  Thank you for your help; You did gave me the SqliteFacade thingie, which I will use from now on (something similar) ;-)